# Ajax file uploading getting duplicate image

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I have downloaded php-ajax multiple upload file from [Multiple File Drag and Drop Upload](https://github.com/arunkumarsekar/Multiple_file_drag_and_drop_upload)

i have setup this code in my local xampp server. This code is working fine when i am uploading original image with no changes but when i rename the file name in first time it works fine second time it is not working. File uploads 2 times in every images. Third time it uploads 3 times in local server simultaneously.

Old Code:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'])){
        echo($_POST['index']);
    }
    exit;
}
?>
```

My Changes Code:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    $photo=time().rand(1,1000).'.'.substr(strrchr($_FILES['file']['name'],'.'),1);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "uploads/".$photo)){
        echo($_POST['index']);
    }
    exit;
}
?>
```

Please help me and tell me how to upload rename images without page refresh?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the tempnam() to get the unique filename.
2. Clean the form content in form.submit() event =)

Comment: How to use `tempnam()`?

Comment: $photo = uniqid('MyApp', true).'.'.substr(strrchr($_FILES['file']['name'],'.'),1);

Comment: $phote = tempnam('./','').'.'.substr(strrchr($_FILES['file']['name'],'.'),1);

Comment: Do you have checked my above code? Please download https://github.com/arunkumarsekar/Multiple_file_drag_and_drop_upload run in your local server. My code is working but when i rename my image my image is uploading repeatedly.